# Error 10049 on Windows Python Multicast

Tags: python, windows, multicast

Here's some Python code to set up a multicast receiver.  It works fine on mac and linux.

```
import socket, struct

ADDR='239.239.250.1'
PORT=8001

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((ADDR, PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(ADDR), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

but receives an error 10049 on the bind when run on windows.

```
Z:\winx>c:\Python27\python.exe q2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q2.py", line 11, in <module>
    sock.bind((ADDR,PORT))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Is there a known problem with windows multicast?  If not, what steps can I take to diagnose?

Comment: Are you sure, the ip address "239.239.250.1" is your machine's? It seems to be network gateway's.

Comment: @Sheng, it's a multicast address.

Comment: did you try specifying it as UDP specifically: `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and from [here](http://www.nealc.com/blog/blog/2012/09/11/testing/) I understood that you need to bind to local host.
`sock.bind(('', PORT))` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong address, assuming that you meant something well-known, e.g. site-local multicast.

Per http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-multicast/ipmlt_wp.pdf this address belongs to [possibly unused] site-local expansion.

Perhaps Windows validates the address for you?