# How to receive multicast UDP data on windows using python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, wireshark

I have a device connected to a windows 10 machine and this device is sending out various multicast UDP packages. I can see them on the windows machine using `wireshark`:

[image]

Now to get them in python (3.10.10) I am using the following script:

```
import struct
import socket
import select

HOST = "192.168.200.5"
MCAST_GRP = "239.0.0.12"
PORT = 45013

def initSocket(group, port, host):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
    # struct.pack converts non-bytes values to bytes. To be used as the last parameter of 
    # setsockopt which needs to be a bytes-like object representing a buffer.
    # "4sl" is a format specifier for a 4-bytes string and a long int.
    mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(group), socket.INADDR_ANY)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    return sock

sock = initSocket(MCAST_GRP, PORT, HOST)
while True:
    ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 1)
    if ready[0]:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
        print(f"received message:  {data}")   
    else:
        print("No data received")
```

But no message seems to be received! I only get `No data received`.

I am running this script as admin, and no other process seems to be using port 45013 (according to `netstat -ano -p udp`). I also allowed the "python" app through the firewall.

The device itself is connected to an ethernet adaptor (with IP address `192.168.200.5`) to the computer via USB. And the computer DOES receive the UDP messages (see wireshark).

`netsh int ip show join` shows

```
Interface 25: Ethernet

Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
0                    0  Yes   224.0.0.1
0                    4  Yes   224.0.0.251
0                    1  Yes   224.0.0.252
0                    3  Yes   239.255.255.250
```

So what else can I try? How to make it work? What is the problem?

Maybe there is a workaround to use wireshark inside python to receive the UDP data?

I have been using a C code to receive the UDP data on a Linux VM running on windows, and after some configuring and re-configuring settings and IP addresses the C code is able to receive the data. But not the python code. The python code now chooses to create a new error (on Linux VM only):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_receiver.py", line 54, in <module>
    sock = initSocket(MCAST_GRP, PORT, HOST)
  File "udp_receiver.py", line 32, in initSocket
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device
```

Comment: Does `netsh int ip show join` confirm that the system has joined the groups?

Comment: Not sure, output here: `Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
0                    0  Yes   224.0.0.1
0                    4  Yes   224.0.0.251
0                    1  Yes   224.0.0.252
0                    3  Yes   239.255.255.250`

Comment: I think you need `sock.bind((MCAST_GRP,port))` rather than binding to all interfaces.

Comment: When I try that I get an error `OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

Comment: On snuffling around, it appears this might be a minefield. One suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599504/2836621 that you can use `''` as the address. No other ideas, sorry.

Comment: Already tried that, no success either

Comment: @MarkSetchell That only works on Linux, and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this same issue for a couple days until I finally found a solution that worked.

Using Python 3.9+  I'm on 3.12.2 and Windows 11 Pro

Fix found here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101960

```html
        import socket        
        
        receive_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        try:
            if udp_setting == "mcast":
                receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        except AttributeError:
            print("Attribute error: ignored")
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Socket options error: {}".format(e))
        
        try:
            if udp_setting == "mcast":
                receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 32) 
                receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 1)

        
            bresult = receive_socket.bind((local_ip, local_port)) # Double parenthese make it a tuple passed as a single argument
            print("bresult: {}".format(bresult))
            receive_socket.settimeout(10) #This prevents an endless time sitting with no data

            if udp_setting == "mcast":
                # Linux
                # mreq = struct.pack('4sl', socket.inet_aton("230.0.0.1"), socket.INADDR_ANY)
                # self.receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
                # Windows
                receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(local_ip))
                receive_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton("multicast ip") + socket.inet_aton(local_ip))

except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Socket binding error: {}".format(e))
```